# Appcelerator Titanium iOS module crashes

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

We are writing a native iOS module for Titanium which can do SAML authentication. I pass the SSO url to the module, it initiates an HTTP request to the url, the url send HTTP 302 redirects 2 times and goes to IDP where it should authenticate and return back the SAML token.

This is the function in my SAML module that I invoke from my Titanium app javascript code:

```
var saml = require('com.xxx.SAML');
    Ti.API.info("module is => " + saml);
    saml.ssoUrl ="https://xxxx";
    saml.startSSO();
```

The module is installed correctly and gets invoked. Below is the function startSSO:

```
-(id)startSSO:(id)args {
    self.samlUtility  = [[SAMLUtility alloc] init];
    [self.samlUtility setSsoUrl:self.ssoUrl];
    [self.samlUtility performSAMLAuth];
    NSLog(@"setSsoUrl ");    }
```

SAML Utility class is as below:

```
@implementation SAMLUtility

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
 completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential * __nullable credential))completionHandler{
    NSLog(@"did receive auth challenge");

    if(challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod  == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust){
        NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, credential);
    }else if(challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM || challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodNegotiate){

        NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"xxxx" password:@"xxxx" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];

        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, credential);

    }else {

        // Cancel request
        NSURLCredential *credential = [[NSURLCredential alloc] init];
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeCancelAuthenticationChallenge, credential);

    }

}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
willPerformHTTPRedirection:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response
        newRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLRequest * __nullable))completionHandler{
    NSLog(@"in redirection");
    NSURLRequest *newRequest = request;
    completionHandler(newRequest);

}

-(void)httpRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest*)request callback:(void(^)(NSData *data, NSString *str))callback{
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    //Manage the time out configuration
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest=120;
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource=120;

    //Now initiate the reuqest
    self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] init];

    if((request) != nil) {
        NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

            if(response){
                NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
                NSLog(@"---- Response Code : %ld",(long)httpResponse.statusCode);
                NSLog(@"---- Header fields Code : %@", httpResponse.allHeaderFields);

                if(error){
                    callback(data, error.localizedDescription);
                } else {

                    callback(data, nil);
                }
            }
            else{
                NSLog(@"---- Response is not NSHTTPURLResponse it is %@ -data: %@ - error: %@",response, data, error);
            }


        }];

        [task resume];
    }

    callback(data, nil);
}

-(void)performSAMLAuth{

    NSString *escapedspEndPoint = [self.ssoUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Calling iDP endpoint added encoded %@",escapedspEndPoint);

    //call SP login end point
    NSURL *urlObject = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedspEndPoint];
    NSMutableURLRequest *spLoginReq = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:urlObject];

    //Create a session and connect to the specfied url.
    NSLog(@"Going to request  now...");

    //TODO: This will result in 302 and go to IdP location do authentication with kerberos
    //other other options and come back...

    [self httpRequest:spLoginReq callback:^(NSData *data, NSString *error){
        if(error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
            NSLog(@"Task execution completed with failure");
        } else {
            NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Success: %@", s);

            //Parse the IdP response and send back to
            //SP SSO End point
            NSMutableURLRequest *spSsoReq = [self buildSsoRequestFrom:data];

            [self httpRequest:spSsoReq callback:^(NSData *data, NSString *error){
                if(error) {
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
                    NSLog(@"Task execution completed with failure");
                } else {
                    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    NSLog(@"Success: %@", s);

                    NSLog(@"spSsoReq completed");
                    NSLog(@"------------------------");
                }
                NSLog(@"Task execution completed");
                NSMutableURLRequest *spSsoReq1 = [self buildSsoRequestFrom:data];
                if([spSsoReq1.URL.absoluteString isEqualToString:@"https://xxxxx/saml2/sp/acs"]){
                    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SSOCompleted" object: nil];
                }

                NSArray *cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies];
                if(cookies.count > 0){
                    for(NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies){
                        NSLog(@"cookie : %@", cookie.name);
                    }
                }

            }];
        }
    }];

}

-(NSMutableURLRequest*)buildSsoRequestFrom:(NSData*)samlHtmlResponse{
    TFHpple *doc = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:samlHtmlResponse];

            if(doc == nil || (doc.data) == nil) {
                NSLog(@"Bad SAML expected response: %@", doc);
                return nil;
            }

    NSArray *elements = [doc searchWithXPathQuery:@"//form"];

    if (elements != nil && elements.count > 0) {

        for(TFHppleElement *element in elements){

            //This is form
            TFHppleElement *formElement = (TFHppleElement*)element;
            NSString *spSsoUrlString = [formElement objectForKey:@"action"];
            NSLog(@"--- Now sending back to SP SSO End point : %@", spSsoUrlString);

            //Now iterate through all the child elements of type input
            NSURL *spSsoUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:spSsoUrlString];
            NSMutableURLRequest *spSsoRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:spSsoUrl];

            //set method to HTTP POST
            spSsoRequest.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

            //set content type for url encoded
            //spSsoRequest.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

            //iterate through all the input parameters
            //and extract key = name & value = value of the input

            NSArray *inputElements = [formElement childrenWithTagName:@"input"];
            NSMutableString *postBody = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            for(TFHppleElement *ie in inputElements) {
                TFHppleElement *tfie = (TFHppleElement*)ie;
                NSString *key = [tfie objectForKey:@"name"];
                NSString *value= [tfie objectForKey:@"value"];
                value = [value stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                value = [value stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, value.length)];
                [postBody stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@=%@",key,value];
            }
            NSLog(@"3. POST Body : %@", postBody);
            NSData *postBodyData = [postBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            spSsoRequest.HTTPBody = postBodyData;

            return spSsoRequest;
        }
    }
    return nil;

}
```

When I run the app, I see the logs stop below and app crashes mentioning Segmentation fault:

```
[INFO] :   [object ComXXXSamlModule] loaded
[INFO] :   module is => [object ComXXXSamlModule]
[INFO] :   2016-07-06 18:01:57.837 myxxx[16912:209092] Calling iDP endpoint added encoded https://xxx
[INFO] :   2016-07-06 18:01:57.838 myxxx[16912:209092] Going to request  now...
[INFO] :   2016-07-06 18:01:57.840 myxxx[16912:209092] Success: 
[INFO] :   2016-07-06 18:01:57.882 myxxx[16912:209092] Document length: 0 (902 in Kerberos-POC)
[INFO] :   2016-07-06 18:01:57.882 myxxx[16912:209092] Unable to parse:
[INFO] :   2016-07-06 18:01:57.882 myxxx[16912:209092] Success: 
[INFO] :   2016-07-06 18:01:57.883 myxxx[16912:209092] spSsoReq completed
[INFO] :   2016-07-06 18:01:57.883 myxxx[16912:209092] ------------------------
[INFO] :   2016-07-06 18:01:57.883 myxxx[16912:209092] Task execution completed
[INFO] :   2016-07-06 18:01:57.883 myxxx[16912:209092] Document length: 0  (5728 in Kerberos-POC)
[INFO] :   2016-07-06 18:01:57.883 myxxx[16912:209092] Unable to parse:
```

However, If I put the same code into my native iOS app and call the same code as in startSSO, the code executes beyond these logs (I see SAML token and more in the logs) and completes the SAML authentication.

Crash logs:

```
Crashed Thread:        5  KrollContext<kroll$1>

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000018
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0x18:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000104e67000-0000000105198000 [ 3268K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FBA2AFBE-14CE-4439-B28A-1AC45FE45639/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/74AA8443-77DE-42FF-BA3F-CE6216FB08D5/myxxx.app/myxxx

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: isKindOfClass:
CoreSimulator 209.19 - Device: iPad Air - Runtime: iOS 9.3 (13E230) - DeviceType: iPad Air

...

Thread 5 Crashed:: KrollContext<kroll$1>
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000010aadb80b objc_msgSend + 11
1   com.xxx.myxxx       0x0000000104e910c7 ConvertIdTiValue + 55 (KrollObject.m:95)
2   com.xxx.myxxx       0x0000000104e92c95 +[KrollObject toValue:value:] + 37 (KrollObject.m:538)
3   com.xxx.myxxx       0x0000000104e8ccfc KrollCallAsFunction + 684 (KrollMethod.m:66)
4   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x0000000105a90bba JSC::JSCallbackObject<JSC::JSDestructibleObject>::call(JSC::ExecState*) + 506
5   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x0000000105b71340 JSC::LLInt::setUpCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::Instruction*, JSC::CodeSpecializationKind, JSC::JSValue, JSC::LLIntCallLinkInfo*) + 528
6   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x0000000105b7835d llint_entry + 22900
7   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x0000000105b78368 llint_entry + 22911
8   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x0000000105b78468 llint_entry + 23167
9   ???                             0x0000061b4034dafa 0 + 6714111089402
10  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x0000000105b727d9 vmEntryToJavaScript + 326
11  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x0000000105a44959 JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 169
12  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x0000000105a2b264 JSC::Interpreter::execute(JSC::ProgramExecutable*, JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*) + 10404
13  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x000000010583b786 JSC::evaluate(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::SourceCode const&, JSC::JSValue, WTF::NakedPtr<JSC::Exception>&) + 470
14  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x0000000105a89fb8 JSEvaluateScript + 424
15  com.xxx.myxxx       0x0000000104e819f1 -[KrollBridge evalFileOnThread:context:] + 1281 (KrollBridge.m:460)
16  com.xxx.myxxx       0x0000000104e8625c -[KrollInvocation invoke:] + 124 (KrollContext.m:108)
17  com.xxx.myxxx       0x0000000104e881d2 -[KrollContext invokeOnThread:method:withObject:callback:selector:] + 194 (KrollContext.m:1147)
18  com.xxx.myxxx       0x0000000104e81b63 -[KrollBridge evalFile:callback:selector:] + 115 (KrollBridge.m:480)
19  com.xxx.myxxx       0x0000000104e82952 -[KrollBridge didStartNewContext:] + 2498 (KrollBridge.m:614)
20  com.xxx.myxxx       0x0000000104e88de8 -[KrollContext main] + 2392 (KrollContext.m:1349)
21  com.apple.Foundation            0x0000000106f1e12b __NSThread__start__ + 1198
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010b9fe99d _pthread_body + 131
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010b9fe91a _pthread_start + 168
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010b9fc351 thread_start + 13
```

Any help would be appreciated since I am unable to understand the cause of the crash based on this.

Comment: Did you guys ever find out the solution to this error?

Comment: No, we didn't. We ended up not using a native module and rewriting the code in javascript :(